# JLabel doesn't show up when calling paint mehtod

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paint

This is small part of my end of year project and I'm trying to add a straight line with JLabel in a JFrame. if i remove the JLabel then the line will show up, else it won't. i only know about java swing therefore i don't have any experience for java graphics. 
**THANK YOU IN ADVANCE :)**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Draw extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Draw frame = new Draw();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Draw() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 569, 461);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Show ");
        lbl.setBounds(263, 90, 49, 14);
        contentPane.add(lbl);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(100, 100, 0, 0);
        g.drawArc(200, 200, 120, 100, 0, 180);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Don't override paint() on a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() on a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. The content pane of the frame already is a JPanel, to there is no need to create another panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Download one of the working examples and modify it for your specific requirement.

Comment: Never paint directly in a JFrame but rather override paintComponent in a JPanel, and when overriding any painting method (paint, paintComponent, paintBorders...), you almost *always* need to call the corresponding super method in your override.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments, **don't override the** `#paint(Graphics g)` method of the `JFrame`. Instead override the `#paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of your `contentPane`.

```
contentPane = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //Don't forget to call the super method
        super.paintComponent(Graphics g);
        //Draw the line
        g.drawLine(100, 100, 0, 0);  //Maybe adapt the line's position
    }
};
```